# How to get the Hololens Locatable Camera view and projection matrices out of the WinRT Windows.Media API

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, hololens

The documentation for the Hololens gives an example of how to extract the Locatable Camera view and projection matrices using the Media Foundation API here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable_camera#locating_the_device_camera_in_the_world.

It claims that this is also possible with the WinRT API, and links to this documentation reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Devices.Core.CameraIntrinsics.

However, this class does not seem to have any API to retrieve the extended Hololens attributes, only the default Windows Phone ones like the distortion matrix and pinhole properties.

Is the Hololens documentation incorrect and is it simply not possible to retrieve the Locatable Camera metadata in the WinRT API? Or am I missing something?

The Spatial Coordinate System (3rd and last extended sample metadata attribute) does seem to be available as *MediaFrameReference.CoordinateSystem* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframereference), which makes this even more confusing...

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the captured [`CapturedPhoto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.capturedphoto) object to [`IMFGetService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface. Then, you can call [`IMFGetService::GetService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696978(v=vs.85).aspx) method with `MF_WRAPPED_SAMPLE_SERVICE` as the service GUID and that will give you the native [`IMFSample`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702192(v=vs.85).aspx). From that, you can retrieve those 3 camera attributes (coordinate system, view transform and projection transform) as outlined in the documentation.

Now, you could try writing doing all that in C# by manually declaring those interfaces, but it would be way easier to do in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The spatial coordinate system of the camera is available through the **MediaFrameReference.CoordinateSystem**. But the projection matrix is not offered in the **MediaFrameReference** class. I solved the issue by looking up the projection matrix in the **MediaFrameReference.Properties** map. The basic idea is shown [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable_camera_in_directx) however i needed to adapt the code for UWP. My working code is shown below.

```
EXTERN_GUID(MFSampleExtension_Spatial_CameraProjectionTransform, 0x47f9fcb5, 0x2a02, 0x4f26, 0xa4, 0x77, 0x79, 0x2f, 0xdf, 0x95, 0x88, 0x6a);

MediaFrameReference^ frame = ...; // your frame
auto projectionTransformProperty= (Windows::Foundation::IPropertyValue^)frame->Properties->Lookup(MFSampleExtension_Spatial_CameraProjectionTransform);
Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ projectionMatrixByteArray = ref new Platform::Array<unsigned char>(4*4*4);
projectionTransformProperty->GetUInt8Array(&projectionMatrixByteArray);
float* projectionMatrixValues= reinterpret_cast<float*>(projectionMatrixByteArray->Data);
//projectionMatrixValues now contains the 16 entries of the projection matrix
```